# Color in Cygwin terminal

Tags: command-line, terminal, cygwin, console

I've installed cygwin because I'm a bit fed up with the Windows terminal not being great.  The only problem I'm having is the lack of colours.

You can see the problem in the following 2 screenshots that display the same command:

[image]
[image]

All I want is something which has a nice font, resizes properly (including proper behaviour when maximised) and support for colours.  Ideally I'd like tabs too.  This seems like a silly reason to end up buying a mac, so I'm hoping I can get all these things on windows somehow.

Comment: try [console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/) - it is a lightweight customizible alternative to cmd.exe. I've been using it for a while now and it does the job

Comment: Aside from the aforementioned _console2_, which is really good, another alternative is _mintty_, which is installable using the cygwin setup. Both allow you to set up profiles, where you can (among others) specify colours and the behaviour of the mouse. Console2 makes it easy to have several tabs inside one Window, while you create separate windows with mintty (similar to xterm). I suggest that you give both a try and see what you like best.

Answer (score 3):

Copy of the answer from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904494/1405560).

I'm the author of [ConEmu](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) - opensource console emulator with tabs, which represents multiple consoles and simple GUI applications as one customizable GUI window.

Initially, the program was designed to work with [Far Manager](http://www.farmanager.com/) (my favorite shell replacement - file and archive management, command history and completion, powerful editor). But ConEmu can be used with any other console application or simple GUI tools (like PuTTY for example). ConEmu is a live project, open to suggestions.

A brief excerpt from the long list of options:

- Smooth resize, maximized and fullscreen window modes
- User friendly text and block selection (from keyboard or mouse), copy, paste, text search in console
- Optional settings (e.g. pallette) for selected applications
- ANSI X3.64 and Xterm 256 color
- Use any font installed in the system, or copied to a folder of the program (ttf, otf, fon, bdf)
- Run selected tabs as Administrator (Vista+) or as selected user
- Windows 7 Jump lists and Progress on taskbar
- Integration with [DosBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) (useful in 64bit systems to run DOS applications)
- Scrollbar initially hidden, may be revealed by mouseover or checkbox in settings

Far Manager users will acquire shell style drag-n-drop, thumbnails and tiles in panles, tabs for editors and viewers, true colors and font styles (italic/bold/underline).

Answer (score 2):

Look at these two alternatives to the default Cygwin terminal,

1. [MinTTY](http://code.google.com/p/mintty/)

   - I prefer this one; am not much of a tab fan -- I like overlapping windows `:-)`
2. [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/)

   - **Multiple Tabs** - Like tabbed browsing, only with terminals
   - Windows x86 .msi: Requires Cygwin <= 1.7.7 and Cygwin Ruby and 32 bit Java.

Answer (score 2):

I found that using a recent Cygwin install (2015-09), I can see colors of my logs in a simple Cygwin Terminal, using `cat` or `more`.

piped with `grep`, it's powerfull enough to see what you want.

No need to install anything else

Comment: The ANSI codes appear in your post - is that what was intended?

Comment: Is this an answer, or are you stating you're still having problems? If it's an answer, please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/972734/edit) to explain a bit more.

Comment: removed the useless part , hope it's clear enough now

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to leave cygwin. You can consider using [**'fish'**](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ffish%2Ffish-3.5.0-1&grep=fish) or [**'zsh'**](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Fzsh%2Fzsh-5.8-1&grep=zsh) prompt shells. I currently use fish which has default color scheme based on cygwin (MinTTYx64).

I also recommend [mintty color schemes](https://github.com/oumu/mintty-color-schemes#usage) would be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Emacs, you may like `M-x shell`. It has all that you suggests, and of course quite a bit more.